# django.contrib.auth.models.Permission.DoesNotExist: Permission matching query does not exist

Tags: django, django-models

While assigning permissions to users, I am getting the error `django.contrib.auth.models.Permission.DoesNotExist: Permission matching query does not exist`.

When I look into the database, I find that models aren't being shown as contenttypes; nor are the default add/change/delete/view permissions being created for them by django.

How can I resolve this issue?

Things I've tried:

1. running `python manage.py migrate` on a new database.... issue persists.
2. unapplying all migrations, then re-applying them... issue persists.
3. applying the auth,contenttypes,sessions,admin migrations before any of my app migrations.. issue persists.

Part of the code snippet I'm using is as follows:

```py
                app = "MyApp"
                model = "MyModel"
                users = "user1"
                userGroup = "group1"
                permissionsString = "advc"
                modelClass = apps.get_model(app, model)
                contentType = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(modelClass)

                if (contentType == None):
                    raise Exception("ContentType isn't available.")

                permissions = Permission.objects.filter(content_type = contentType)
                for permissionLiteral in permissionsString:
                    if (permissionLiteral == 'a'):
                        permission = permissions.get(codename__startswith = 'add_')
                    elif (permissionLiteral == 'c'):
                        permission = permissions.get(codename__startswith = 'change_')
                    elif (permissionLiteral == 'd'):
                        permission = permissions.get(codename__startswith = 'delete_')
                    elif (permissionLiteral == 'v'):
                        permission = permissions.get(codename__startswith = 'view_')
                    else:
                        raise Exception("Invalid permission literal.")
                    if (permission != None):
                        group.permissions.add(permission)
```

- app = my app's name being passed to function
- model = model name being passed to function
- permissionsString = passed 'advc' for all 4 permissions; 'v' for only the view permissions.

The error `django.contrib.auth.models.Permission.DoesNotExist: Permission matching query does not exist` is raised when any of the `permission = permissions.get(...)` statements are executed.

Comment: by default, django will create 4 crud permission for model class. Maybe need more detail for check what happend made your permission not like normal. 
Can you show DB, field in django, migrate of it? Or any details you have?

Comment: If you can let me know what you need to see and how I can make you see it, I'll show it.

Comment: 1. Code Model missing permission 
2. Migrate of model missing permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, thanks to the [#django IRC channel](https://web.libera.chat/#django).

So, the issue is that content_types and permissions are created by a post_migration signal; not during a migrations. That's why, they aren't available at the time of migrations. (For more, read [this django discussion](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23422))

Therefore, we need to follow these standard practices as django devs:

1. Migrations need to be reserved exclusively for schematic changes to the database; do not perform data migrations and permissions assignments as part of migrations.
2. For data migrations and permissions' assignments, create django-admin commands. django-admin commands are explained in the django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Thanks again to hop and dodo in the django IRC channel. Special thanks to hop for overnight troubleshooting and solutioning of this issue.